# Modal Logic: proof or refute

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I have the following statement:

$(A \land B) \rightarrow \square\lozenge(A \lor B)$ characterizes symmetry.

I am pretty sure there exists a proof for that statement since I am unable to find some counterexample.

But I am really struggling with a formal proof.

What I have done until now:

We need to prove two directions:

1. For all symmetric frames $\mathcal{F}$ we have $\mathcal{F} \vDash (A \land B) \rightarrow \square\lozenge(A \lor B)$
2. $\mathcal{F} \vDash (A \land B) \rightarrow \square\lozenge(A \lor B)$ implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is symmetric

But how do I correctly prove those?

Comment: I recommend that you don't use $\supset$ for implication. This is an outdated and confusing notation. Use $\rightarrow$ instead.

Comment: Can you prove either of the two directions? (1) is the "easy" one.

Comment: yeah I know, unfortunately we a forced to use $\supset$ in the context of intuitionistic- and modal-logic

Comment: Can you prove that $P\rightarrow \square\lozenge P$ characterizes symmetry? One approach would be to start with that proof and see how you have to modify it to deal with the formulas $A\land B$ and $A\lor B$.

Comment: (1) Suppose that $P \rightarrow \square \diamond P$ is valid in $\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be any model $\langle W,R,V \rangle$ based on $\mathcal{F}$ and $w_1, w_2 \in W$. Let $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, w_1)$ = 1 and therefore also $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P \rightarrow \square \diamond P, w_1)$ = 1 by assumption, $V_{\mathcal{M}}(\diamond P, w_2)$ = 1 such that $w_1 R w_2$. Also $V_{\mathcal{M}}(\diamond P, w_2)$ = 1, which means there is a $y$ such that $w_2 R y$ and $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, y)$ = 1, but this means that $t=w_1$ and thus $x R w_1$

Comment: (2) Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a symmetric frame and $\mathcal{M}$ any model based on $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose 
$V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, w_1)$ = 1. If $V_{\mathcal{M}}(\square P, w_1)$ = 0 than there is a $w_2$ such that $w_1 R w_2$, with $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, \diamond w_2)$ = 0. This means for no $y$ with $w_2 R y$ we have $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, y)$ = 1. Since R is symmetric, $w_2 R w_1$ so $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P, w_1)$ = 0 is a contradiction. Therefore we get $V_{\mathcal{M}}(\square \diamond P, w_1)$ = 1 and also $V_{\mathcal{M}}(P \rightarrow \square \diamond P, w_1)$ = 1

Comment: I don't follow your proof of (1). Certainly if $P$ is true at $w_1$, then $\square\lozenge P$ is true at $w_1$. (a) You can't conclude $\lozenge P$ is true at $w_2$ unless you know $w_1Rw_2$. You say "such that $w_1Rw_2$" after the assertion, but you fixed arbitrary $w_1,w_2\in W$ at the beginning. If you want to assume $w_1Rw_2$, you need to make that assumption when you introduce the variables. (b) Ok, so if $w_1Rw_2$, then $\lozenge P$ is true at $w_2$. So there is some $w_3$ such that $P$ is true at $w_3$ and $w_2Rw_3$. How do you know $w_3 = w_1$?

Comment: Your proof of (2) is correct (though there is a typo $\square P$ instead of $\square \lozenge P$. What happens if the hypotheses are that $A\land B$ is true at $w_1$ and $\square \lozenge (A\lor B)$ is false at $w_1$?

Comment: For (1): Sorry I mismatched variable names in the end. (a) So should I fix that assumption at the beginning? (b) Would that be the case because of $w_3 \in V_{\mathcal{M}}(P)$ ?

Comment: For (2): Then there would be an $w_2$ with $w_1 R w_2$ where $\diamond(A \lor B)$ is false. So for no $w_3$ with $w_2 R w_3$ we get that $V_{\mathcal{M}}(A \lor B, w_3)$ is true. But that cant be the case since R is symmetric and we know that $A,B$ are true since $A \land B$ is true?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a symmetric frame. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a model based on $\mathcal{F}$. We would like to show that $(A\land B)\to \square\lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at every world. So let $w$ be a world, and assume $A\land B$ is true at $w$. Let $v$ be a world such that $wRv$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is symmetric, $vRw$. Since $A\land B$ is true at $w$, $A\lor B$ is true at $w$, so $\lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at $v$. Since $v$ was arbitrary, $\square \lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at $w$.
2. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a frame validating $(A\land B)\to \square\lozenge (A\lor B)$. Assume for contradiction that $\mathcal{F}$ is not symmetric. Then there exist worlds $w$ and $v$ such that $wRv$ but $\lnot v R w$. Consider the model $\mathcal{M}$ based on $\mathcal{F}$ where $A$ and $B$ are both true at $w$ and $A$ and $B$ are both false at all other worlds. Then $(A\land B)$ is true at $w$. Since $(A\land B)\to \square\lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at every world, $\square \lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at $w$. Since $wRv$, $\lozenge (A\lor B)$ is true at $v$. So there is some world $u$ such that $vRu$ and $(A\lor B)$ is true at $u$. Since $\lnot vRw$, $u\neq w$. But by our definition of the model, $A$ and $B$ are both false at $u$, so $\lnot (A\lor B)$ is true at $u$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We can formulate the contention for the basic modal language as

$$(A\wedge B)\rightarrow\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)\text{ is a valid formula in a frame }F\iff F\text{ is a symmetric frame}$$

We shall consider a frame $F=\langle W, R\rangle$ and an associated model $\mathcal{M}=\langle W, R, V\rangle$, where $W$ is a nonempty set of worlds, $R$ is a binary accessibility relation on $W$, and $V$ is a valuation function assigning to each propositional variable $p$ a set $V(p)$ of possible worlds. The following equivalences will get employed:

$(i)\qquad wRw'\text{ holds}\iff w'\text{ is accessible from }w$

$(ii)\qquad w\in V(p)\iff p\text{ is true at }w$

$(iii)\qquad p\text{ is true at }w\iff\mathcal{M}, w\vDash p$

Let us begin with the left-to-right direction:

$$(A\wedge B)\rightarrow\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)\text{ is a valid formula in }F\implies F\text{ is symmetric}$$

So, we suppose $(A\wedge B)\rightarrow\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)$ is a valid formula in a frame $F$ and a world $w_{0}$ such that $w_{0}Rw_{i}$ if there exists an accessible world $w_{i}$. Then, we have

$$\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash A\wedge B\text{ or }\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)\implies F\text{ is symmetric}$$

which fits into the schema $((\neg\phi\vee\psi)\rightarrow\theta)\leftrightarrow((\neg\phi\rightarrow\theta)\wedge(\psi\rightarrow\theta))$. Hence, a common valuation for $A$ and $B$ is required to be used for both disjuncts in the antecedent; we shall not examine each valuation, but it should not be difficult to see that the combinations of the following arguments work for all valuations.

In the first disjunct of the antecedent, $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash A$ or $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash B$. Therefore, that $w_{0}\notin V(A)$ or $w_{0}\notin V(B)$ suffices (because of non-modality) for the consequent vacuously to hold, i.e., that $F$ is symmetric can be assigned true.

In the second disjunct of the antecedent, $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)$. Then, that $w_{0}\in V(A)$ or $w_{0}\in V(B)$ must hold. For the sake of simplicity, let us choose $w_{0}\in V(A)$ and set $V(A)=\{w_{0}\}$ and $V(B)=\emptyset$ without loss of generality. Thus, $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash A$ and $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash A\vee B$. We have

$$\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)\iff\mathcal{M}, w_{i}\vDash\Diamond (A\vee B)\text{ for all }w_{i}\text{ such that }w_{0}Rw_{i}$$

and for some $w_{i}$

$$\mathcal{M}, w_{i}\vDash\Diamond(A\vee B)\iff\mathcal{M}, w_{j}\vDash A\vee B\text{ such that }w_{i}Rw_{j}$$

By our assumptions, $w_{j}\in V(A)$, thus $w_{j}=w_{0}$, hence, $w_{i}Rw_{0}$. Therefore, $F$ is symmetric.

Let us examine the right-to-left direction; so, we assume $F$ a symmetric frame:

$$F\text{ is symmetric}\implies (A\wedge B)\rightarrow\Box\Diamond(A\vee B)\text{ is a valid formula in }F$$

A shortcut for this case is to show that supposing the consequent to be false leads to a contradiction. So, we take $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash A\wedge B$ and $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash\Box\Diamond (A\vee B)$. We have

$$\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash\Box\Diamond (A\vee B)\iff\mathcal{M}, w_{i}\nvDash\Diamond (A\vee B)\text{ for some }w_{i}\text{ such that }w_{0}Rw_{i}$$

$$\mathcal{M}, w_{i}\nvDash\Diamond (A\vee B)\text{ for some }w_{i}\text{ such that }w_{0}Rw_{i}\iff\mathcal{M}, w_{j}\nvDash A\vee B\text{ for all }w_{j}\text{ such that }w_{i}Rw_{j}$$

But one of the $w_{j}$ must be $w_{0}$ by our assumption that $R$ is symmetric, hence, $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\nvDash A\vee B$, which contradicts our supposition that $\mathcal{M}, w_{0}\vDash A\wedge B$. Therefore, the consequent cannot be false, given the antecedent.